# Are my variables dependent or independent?

Tags: independence, biostatistics

I have 2 sets of variables that I need to run tests on and I am not sure if they are dependent or independent.  I will describe them below:

Set 1: these values are river water samples that I collected over the past 6 months.

Set 2: these values are grass carp otoliths (structures that can chemically show the life of the fish) collected a few years ago

I am questioning the independence of these variables because the water chemistry should determine the chemical makeup of the otolith.  So in that regard, Set 2 should be dependent on Set 1.  However, because they are not paired and were not collected at the same time, I am unsure if this would make them independent.

My end goal is to determine whether or not the two sets of variables are correlated in any way, so I am trying to determine what statistical test to use on them (any input on that is also welcome).  But before I can do that, I need to figure out their (in)dependence.

Answer (score 0):

How are those two variables connected? You need to come up with pairs (water sample, otolith) before you can do independence tests. And for this pairing you need a connection. Only you can provide this connection, I can only guess.
E.g. it might make sense to pair them by river, i.e. you put a water sample $s$ and an otolith $o$ into a pair $(s, o)$ exactly when both come from the same river.

Once you have your pairs, you can think about your independence test. Here it is important to know of what type your data is, i.e. is it continuous or categorical. For categorical data, people often use Pearson's chi-squared test. For continuous data, either binning or e.g. Hoeffding's test are possibilities.

For more information, you might want to give more information about what your actual final goal is.